# Django (3.0) test.py - проблема с созданием тестовой базы данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Возникла проблема по созданию тестов django, а конкретнее, не создается поле `slug`  в тестовой БД *(PostgreSql)*. Если дать права суперпользователя также ничего не меняется.

```py
# models.py

class PostModel(models.Model):
    auth_name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=120, null=False, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Image', null=True, blank=True, upload_to='post_img/',
                              default='post_img/default.jpg')
    content = RichTextUploadingField('Short description', null=True, blank=True)
    content_2 = RichTextUploadingField('Post text', blank=True, null=True, config_name='special', )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField('Published date', auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name='URL')  # editable=False,
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

```py
# tests.py

from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import PostModel
User = get_user_model()


class PostTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        user_obj = User.objects.create(username='testuser', email='test@ukr.net')
        user_obj.set_password('somepassword')
        user_obj.save()

    def test_single_user(self):
        user_count = User.objects.count()
        self.assertEqual(user_count, 1)
```

После **python manage.py test**:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: PostModel has no field named 'slug'
```

На screenshot также видно, что колонки `slug` нет в тестовой таблице
[image: postmodel]

Переподключение на `SqLite` бд также результата не дало

что не так?

Answer (score 0):

**Решено.** Скорее всего проблема была в миграциях, хоть до этого проблем с ними не было. 
 Удалил все миграции (бд соответствует последней миграции), и создал новую без применения по той же модели и без изменений. Тесты запустились.